# How to access css3 transform rotate in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Friends,

I am trying to rotate image using css3. On w3schools i found :

```
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg); // IE 9 
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); // Safari and Chrome 
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg); // Firefox 
-o-transform: rotate(45deg); // Opera
```

So i am dynamically rotating i.e. changing rotational angle using javascript.
So i am able to rotate it Mozilla, Safari, Chrome browser with following code:

```
document.getElementById("testimg").style.MozTransform = 'rotate('+i+'deg)'; 
document.getElementById("testimg").style.WebkitTransform = 'rotate('+i+'deg)';
```

So can somebody tell me how to do this for IE9 & Opera???

Comment: I succeed for Opera using OTransform. Please tell me for IE9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `msTransform`:

```
document.getElementById("testimg").style.msTransform = 'rotate('+i+'deg)';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tEC8W/

Comment: yes david its working, but i dont know what the problm with my code
In your code you used div so i am using image but dont know what is the cause to it